# Jquery accordion slow loading on value binding

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I have a jquery accordion that takes a long time to collapse when the page loads.

I know why this is, as I have many muiltselect listboxes inside this accordion which some contain 2000+ values. so the binding to these listboxes is what is causing the slowness

Example of a listbox HTML

```
// Model.Enquiry.People contains over 2000+ values

@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.ID, new MultiSelectList(Model.Enquiry.People, "Id", "Name"), new { multiple = "multiple", @class = "multiselect" })
```

Of course, (probably) the right answer to this problem is to cut down the amount of values I am binding to the listboxes, but if I cannot do this, is **it possible to bind the listboxes when I click on the accordion section? Or is there anything else I could do?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, i did a workaround...

I just hid the accordion in the `div style="visibility:hidden;"` and inside `$(document).ready` I just used

```
$('#accordion').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

But its not wise to be binding so much in the first place! the real answer!

Answer (score 0):

Do your `accordion` have an animation? If yes, turn of your animation, just use simple `show` and `hide` of the element, maybe that can help your performance.